# How can I "lock" a LineRenderer and make it only follow one direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, touch, lerp

So I have two predetermined points and I want to draw a line between them.

[image]

I don't have an issue with actually drawing the line or snapping it to final position, but I want to lock it in between the two points while it's drawing. At the moment, it follows my touch's position in all directions.

Here's what it currently does:
[image: What happens at the moment]

Here's an approximation of what I'm trying to do (finger still on screen):
[image: Desired effect]

And here's how the line looks when it connects with the final point (finger has been lifted and line is still drawn):
[image: Final Position after finger has been lifted]

```
    public class Path : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector3[] positions;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject child1, child2;

    private Vector3 startPos, currentPos, endPos;

    [SerializeField] private bool _firstChildSelected = false;
    [SerializeField] private bool _secondChildSelected = false;

    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    Vector3 direction;

    Touch touch;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[4];
        endPos = child2.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position), Vector2.zero);


            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
            {
                if (hit)
                {
                    // If it collides with the first checkpoint for the first time...
                    if (hit.transform.gameObject == child1 && !_firstChildSelected)
                    {
                        positions[0] = child1.transform.position;
                        line.SetPosition(0, positions[0]);
                        line.SetPosition(1, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position));
                        _firstChildSelected = true;

                    }

                    // If it collides with the second checkpoint for the first time, and already passed by the first one... 
                    if (hit.transform.gameObject == child2 && _firstChildSelected && !_secondChildSelected)
                    {
                        _secondChildSelected = true;
                    }
                }

                // Follow the touch.position until it reached the final position...
                else if (_firstChildSelected)
                {
                    currentPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
                    direction = (endPos - positions[0]).normalized;
                    line.SetPosition(1, currentPos);

                }

                // When both have been selected, lock the line in
                if (_firstChildSelected == true && _secondChildSelected == true)
                {
                    currentPos = child2.transform.position;
                    line.SetPosition(1, currentPos);
                }
            }

            // Clear all on finger lift, but keep the line drawn
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                Array.Clear(positions, 0, positions.Length);
                _firstChildSelected = false;
                _secondChildSelected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know my code is messy, I'm kinda new to all this and I've been trying out some stuff. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is it you want help with? "but I want to lock it in between the two points while it's drawing"

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm having a bit of a hard time explaining it (hence all the images). So I drag the touch from the first point to the second point to create the line, but I want that line to always follow the same path (always from the first to the second). So if the player were to slide their finger halfway between the points, it would draw the line and stop at the touch position, but if the touch's direction is not towards the second point, I don't want it to be drawn. Basically, I want that line to be "locked" in that direction, but I don't know how to use said direction. Hope that's clearer!